# java rotating a 2D image using opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics, lwjgl

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but I just cant make any sense out of them.  Is there any way to easily rotate a 2D object without rotating the whole screen?

Comment: The idea is to have a separate modelview matrix - in particular a separate rotation component - for the 2D object which is different from the one applied to the whole scene.

Comment: You probably need to push/pop current matrix before/after you apply any additional rotation matrix to your specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson 3 of the NeHe GL tutorial shows how to rotate 2d objects with GL: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/

At the end, there is a link to LWJGL code.